# Facebook API - Check every person from a private group to see their "liked" pages

Tags: facebook

I am in this private group and I'd like to check every user in this group to see if they have their "liked" pages for public display. If they do have their "liked" pages for public display, I'd like to search it to see if they have a certain page "liked". Is this possible?

Comment: Sure. Have them log to your app and grant your app user_likes permission. Then you can use the API to go through their likes.

Comment: @WizKid actually I want it to search them like said and if they don't have their "Liked" pages public, I was going to add their name to a list. So is it still possible without their input?

Comment: Not using the API. You can manually go to their profile and look at it